# Action bar does not show

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I tried to implement an action bar in my application.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemAdd"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="ADD">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemRefresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="REFRESH">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemHelp"
        android:title="HELP">
    </item>

</menu>
```

And created menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

But it does not show the action bar even if `minSdkVersion` is 11. What is the reason?

Comment: What theme have you set for your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"

Comment: Do you happen to use: `public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    return new MenuInflater(this);
}` ? Or to call it like `getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);` ?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> Remove your theme for your actionbar activity
>   in androidManifest file. Now it will work...

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/tasktodo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
```

Don't add any theme in your application manifest file. If you added one, please remove and try running it...

Comment: Thank you for providing the simplest solution :-)

Comment: Struggled like 60 minutes wondering why action bar / menu is not showing before found this, jesus f christ... Thanks dude.

Answer (score 7):

change Activity to AppCompatActivity in your class. That should be the easiest if you want to add it fast.. I'll add the code for someone who is new to Android OS:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
```

into

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the style of your Activity to `Theme.Holo` or one of its variants for the ActionBar to show. If you want to keep backwards-compatibility, call setTheme in onCreate of your Activity:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
```

Answer (score 5):

An application with a Manifest like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.Actionbartest"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Menu.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
            android:id="@+id/itemAdd"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="ADD">
    </item>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/itemRefresh"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="REFRESH">
    </item>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/itemHelp"
            android:title="HELP">
    </item>
</menu>
```

And Activity like this

```
package com.example.Actionbartest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Looks like this.

[image]

Are you sure your phone or emulator is running Android 3.0 or above? If not, you will end up with your screenshot.

To enable The Actionbar on older devices, you should use the AppCompat/support library (https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)

Comment: after removing theme i m getting error 02-05 12:02:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(8856): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 2):

```
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

this works. Put it in your

Answer (score 2):

I import `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

then edit to `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Add to dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... >

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Put the RTA label here ... -->
            <meta-data android:name="RTA" android:value="RTA-5042-1996-1400-1577-RTA" />

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the theme at res>values>themes.xml

change the parent to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.Android_Test_2_1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your dark theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_dark_primary</item> -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

It works for me