# Android actionbar not visible

Tags: android

I am trying to add an option menu in actionbar to my existing app but it is not working. If I create a new project with "hello world" default app I can see the button in action bar.  The onCreateOptionMenu() method seems never caught in debug with breakpoint, what's wrong ??

I'm working with API 14 on both app and this is my MainActivity code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Principale extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ecran_d_acceuil);


}
public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.principale, menu);
    return true;
}
 }
```

My menu.xml code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.Principale"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.ListDir"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_dir" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the menu item's showAsAction="never". Trying changing it to showAsAction="always|ifRoom"

Comment: just extend the `AppCompactActivity` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried to set the app theme to a theme that supports the `ActionBar`, like `Theme.Holo.Light`?

Also, in your `Activity` you can try `getActionBar().show();`.

Comment: yes i'am using a Holo.Theme that include ActionBar and already tried getActionBar().show(); the method onCreateOption is never called

Comment: Can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: What's in `AppTheme`?  I don't know why your ActionBar isn't showing.

Comment: I just created a new project with the same settings and everything worked... I didn't even have to call `show()` on the `ActionBar`

Comment: isn't a library or build problem ? a new project works also for me. But when i want to implement these action bar in my existing app no button

Comment: I guess you could just move your code to the new project.  It's inefficient but it gets the job done.  You may have accidentally messed up your project configuration.

Answer (score 22):

In my case, what fixed the issue, was the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919933/action-bar-do-not-show-in-android); to remove

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

from the  tag in the Manifest.

Comment: Alternatively, change the theme to one with Actionbar in @style/AppTheme.  Removing the @style/AppTheme from manifest might also remove the custom UI changes for the App. Eg: colorscheme of UI.

Answer (score 14):

Principale extends ActionBarActivity should take care of the issue

Answer (score 8):

You have extended Activity. Try extending ActionBarActivity in java code

Comment: As an update, ActionBarActivity is deprecated, use AppCompatActivity instead.

Answer (score 7):

For your information, I solved my problem of the actionBar by going on the layout XML file and then pressing on View Option -> Show Layout Decorations.

[image: View Option is the little eye just under the Select Design Surface]

Hope it will solve your problem.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Spent 3 hours and eventually fixed it! Forget removing android:theme="@style/AppTheme" from your manifest. It makes run-time error. 
This is how I fixed the problem. Your activity should extend AppCompatActivity instead of Activity.

Comment: I also spent numerous hours trying to track this down. by making my Activity extends AppCompatActivity the ActionBar appeared as it should.

Answer (score 3):

Check Your manifest file In the Activity declaration if this line is there then delete it.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 2):

your main activity needs to be like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    actionBar.show();
    actionBar.setSubtitle("subtitle");
    actionBar.setTitle("title"); 


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_refresh:
      Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
      break;

         default:
             break;
             }
    return true;
    } 



}
```

and your main.xml like this:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <item
         android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
         android:orderInCategory="100"
         android:showAsAction="always"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
         android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

this is a good and simple guide to creating an action bar:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Comment: Thanks but why the simple hello world app works with only the onCreate method and onCreateOptionMenu ?

Comment: try changing minimum API to 11

Answer (score 2):

on create of your activity.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.action_bar_customvieew, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is saved my time. Please add --actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);   -- in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

What solved my issue in this regard was, in the `design view`, click the `eye` icon (`view options`) and select `Show Layout Decorations`.

[image: Image Showing the Eye Icon in the IDE of Android Studio 3.5]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in your layout .xml file.

Comment: is that giving the same effect as "<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>" ? @JanZiesse ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case
Action bar menu was not visible
when used 
public class  MainActivity  extends Activity {
}
but was visible when used
public class  MainActivity  extends ActionBarActivity{
}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I confirm that if you delete `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` from `AndroidManifest.xml`, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should extend `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the method setHasOptionsMenu(true); in the OnCreate Method

Comment: That's required only in fragments. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

i am using Samsung young 2 as android emulator and i have the same problem ,i reslov this by removing 
`android:theme =""` from the manifest.xml and changing the theme to another theme support action bar

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Simply paste this code in your java *onCreate* function.

Answer (score -1):

My Android studio version is 4.2.1 for Windows 64-bit (933 MiB). In my case, I did not have the "Show Layout Decorations" option in the design view. What I did is I solved my problem of the action bar by going on the layout XML file and then pressing on View Option -> Show System UI

ActionBar visibility in android studio：

[image]