# Action Bar not Displaying

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I'm trying to put an up button on my action bar, but my app isn't displaying the action bar for the fragment. My main activity's fragment has an action bar, just not the fragment it launches, so when I call `getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, the app throws a nullPointerException. (Stack trace for this below at NPE Stack Trace 1).

I've tried using `getActionBar.show()` and setting the theme to Theme.Holo.Light, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950960/android-actionbar-not-visible). `getActionBar.show()`, but that crashes the app with a nullPointerException. When I try to use Theme.Holo.Light, it tells me I have to use an appcompat theme ("You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.")

I've looked around for how to fix that error, but none of the AppCompat themes people suggest solve the problem of there being no action bar on this fragment. Any suggestions people have are appreciated. Code below.

The fragment that won't display an action bar:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent,crime_id";

private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "date";
private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;

private Crime mCrime;
private EditText mTitleField;
private Button mDateButton;
private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    UUID crimeId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

    mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
}

@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null)  {
            //getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
    mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //This space intentionally left blank
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count) {
            mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //This space intentionally left blank
        }
    });

    mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
    updateDate();
    mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
            dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_DATE);
        }
    });

    mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
    mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
    mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE)    {
        Date date = (Date)data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        mCrime.setDate(date);
        updateDate();
    }
}

public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId)   {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);

    CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())    {
        case R.id.home:
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null)  {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void updateDate()   {
    mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
}
}
```

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/crime_title_label"
    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/crime_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/crime_details_label"
    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/crime_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/crime_solved_label"
    />
```

Activity hosting fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CrimePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewpager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
        @Override
        public int getCount()   {
            return mCrimes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(pos);
            return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
        }
    });

    UUID crimeId = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
    for (int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++)    {
        if (mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeId)) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)    {}

        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float posOffset, int posOffsetPixels)  {}

        public void onPageSelected(int pos)    {
            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(pos);
            if (crime.getTitle() != null)   {
                setTitle(crime.getTitle());
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"   />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"   />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
       <activity
        android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                      android:value=".CrimeListActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

res/styles:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

NPE Stack Trace 1:

```
Process: com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent, PID: 24448
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onCreateView(CrimeFragment.java:57)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:479)
        at android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1396)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1595)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6632)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your XML layout files of your Activity and Fragment as well as your Activity class where you should have set your ActionBar.

Comment: Added those. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Your code is very old. You need to get familiar with new APIs. For example extend your activity with AppCompatActivity class as you are using AppCompat theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CrimePagerActivity probably wants to extend ActionBarActivity rather than FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0):

> when I call
>   `getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, the app
>   throws a nullPointerException.

When you are calling this function and saying yourself that you have ActionBar in your Fragment and not in your Activity then how can you run this command.

> I've tried using getActionBar.show() and setting the theme to Theme.Holo.Light, as suggested here. getActionBar.show()

That example is outdated and there's no more Holo Theme or ActionBar. There's `Toolbar` now.