# Why does having android:theme="@style/AppTheme" cause the action bar in my app to go away?

Tags: android

Edit: I understand that this belongs in the comments of the SO post I'm referencing but I don't have the reputation to comment. Downvote away if you feel it's right to do so.

I have the exact same issue as this person on SO: [Android actionbar not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950960/android-actionbar-not-visible) and multiple people suggested removing "android:theme="@style/AppTheme" from the AndroidManifest.xml file. This does fix my problem but I haven't been able to find an answer that explains why this is the case.

1. Why does setting a theme in manifest interfere with the action bar?
2. Where are we supposed to set the app theme if not in manifest (and what's the correct way to set themes)?

Comment: You should have put this in a comment on the original question.

Comment: @thesecretmaster Not enough reputation :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that this question is getting downvoted because it really belongs in the comments. I am very sorry that someone who seems to be a good user with good intentions is stuck under the rep limit for comments, but the limit is there for a reason, and we would like for you to give back to the site (e.g. editing) to get the rep you need to comment. (I think thats the point, if I'm getting it wrong can a more experienced user please correct me?)

Comment: @thesecretmaster http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Thanks @F43nd1r,  I knew there was a meta question about that somewhere, just couldn't find it!

Answer (score 3):

The actionbar is an attribute of themes. Instead of removing the theme, you should modify it:

Add these

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

---

I think that also answers 1. (and by the way if you would set this theme in code the actionbar would disappear too.)

2: The correct way to set themes is in manifest for static themes, and code for dynamic themes.

Comment: Thank you - this clear it up a lot. Follow-up question: I was following a book and had my min. API level set to 8. Why did removing android:theme=“@style/AppTheme” get my action bar back, even when action bars are API 11+?

Comment: I think if you set no theme the default theme is chosen by the device. You might not see an actionbar if you run it on an API 8 phone.

Comment: Oh, right. Min API = 8 doesn't mean it will be run as API 8 on a newer phone. Thank you!

Comment: that would be target API = 8