# Android Action bar not showing up anymore?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, android-actionbar, toolbar

I am making an android app and while changing themes for the design I by mistake remove the actionbar at the top.
Here is my Styles.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/window_background</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>



</style>


<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" 
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

How can I make it appear again?

Comment: make parent theme as Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar ! that should place a bar at start and then after that your custom HOLO bar theme should work

Comment: it shows only in one activity or what?

Comment: It doesn't show it for any activity

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the app? Or you could tried to remove the theme in `<application>` of `AndroidManifest.xml`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919933/action-bar-does-not-show